Why ever store ACTIONS_RUNNER_DEBUG or ACTIONS_STEP_DEBUG as a secret?
Github supports storing ACTIONS_RUNNER_DEBUG or ACTIONS_STEP_DEBUG as a secret or a variable? Why would you ever want to store this as a secret if the value can only be "true"?

In GitHub Actions, ACTIONS_STEP_DEBUG or ACTIONS_RUNNER_DEBUG is a special reserved environment variable that can be set to enable debug logging for steps in a workflow. It's not typically used as a secret, but you can manage it either as a secret or a variable depending on the context and the level of control you want over its value.
ACTIONS_STEP_DEBUG as a Secret:
While ACTIONS_STEP_DEBUG is not inherently sensitive, there might be cases where you want to control access to debug information based on the repository's environment (e.g., only certain teams or users should enable debug logs).
name: Debug Workflow Example

on: [push]

jobs:
  debug-job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Enable Debug Mode
        run: |
          echo "ACTIONS_STEP_DEBUG=${{ secrets.ACTIONS_STEP_DEBUG }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
        env:
          ACTIONS_STEP_DEBUG: ${{ secrets.ACTIONS_STEP_DEBUG }}

      - name: Run a step with debug information
        run: |
          echo "This is a debug step"
          # Here debug logs will appear based on the value of ACTIONS_STEP_DEBUG

ACTIONS_STEP_DEBUG as a Variable:
If you don't have sensitive control over enabling debug mode and want to control it as part of the workflow (maybe to toggle it dynamically), then using it as a variable makes more sense.
name: Debug Workflow Example

on: [push]

jobs:
  debug-job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Enable Debug Mode
        run: |
          echo "ACTIONS_STEP_DEBUG=true" >> $GITHUB_ENV
        env:
          ACTIONS_STEP_DEBUG: ${{ secrets.ACTIONS_STEP_DEBUG }} # If secret used

      - name: Run a step with debug information
        run: |
          echo "This is a debug step"
          # Here debug logs will appear based on the value of ACTIONS_STEP_DEBUG

In practice, ACTIONS_STEP_DEBUG or ACTIONS_RUNNER_DEBUG is often set via environment variables, and it typically doesn't need to be treated as a secret unless you are working with particular security or access control needs.

This answer doesn't make sense to me. Anyone who runs a workflow will know if debugging is enabled. It'll show in the log. It's not a secret that it runs. And if they value itself isn't sensitive how could whether or not it's running be sensitive, all the more when it running is determined only by the value.

@EvanCarroll, I have updated the answer. Please check

Did you write this answer with AI?

Nope. I referred on it along with other articles.
